# WPF Webbrowser - Access to Document Body on IE11

Tags: c#, wpf, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I'm developing a Desktop application which stores the GUI layer on html files as embedded resources. And I have a WPF Web Browser that manages the user interface lifecycle. I'm able to do all the job with no problems. But I've recently found out that when enabling the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION to IE 11 (11000), the document body becomes inaccessible. Then, when using IE 10 (10000) everything works nicely.

The example below shows how to get the document body OffsetHeight:

```
dynamic document = (this.wbContent.Document as dynamic);
if ((document == null) || (document.body == null)) return 0;
return document.body.OffsetHeight;
```

The HTML is:

```
<html>
    ...
    <body style="width: 170px; height: 240px">
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

When using IE 11 it throws an exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'.

When using IE 10 it returns 240.

Have you got any idea about how to access body on IE 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I did not get any answer about solving the problem, I had to trick in order to work around the bug. What is did is to put a simple JavaScript on the html file, so I call the method window.resizeTo(a, b). After this event is called, the application get back working, but I actually don't know why.